# Bash processing of csv file with unknown number of columns

Tags: bash, csv

I am trying to learn some text processing using bash.

How to make a bash script to read and process CSV file with unknown number of columns with first row as column headers?

Example input:

```
column1,column2,...,columnn
value11,value12,...,value1n
value21,value22,...,value2n
...
valuem1,valuem2,...,valuemn
```

output:

```
column1: value11
column2: value12
...
columnn: value1n

column1: value21
column2: value22
...
columnn: value2n

...

column1: valuem1
column2: valuem2
...
columnn: valuemn
```

Comment: I'd suggest using Python or Perl and using their csv modules

Answer (score 8):

One simple approach is to set `IFS=,` and use `read -a` to read into an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=','
read -a headers
while read -a line; do
    for i in "${!line[@]}"; do
        echo "${headers[i]}: ${line[i]}"
    done
done
```

What happens is that the first line is read into the one-dimensional array `$line`, being split according to the character in `$IFS`. Subsequent lines are read in the same way while there is input available, and the `!` in `"${!line[@]}"` instructs bash to loop over array indices instead of array values.

This will not work if the data use any sort of escaping method to include comma literals.